# Limit total entries displayed by datalist

Tags: javascript, css, html, html-datalist

When there is a long set of elements in a datalist, they will all get displayed with a scroll bar next to them. Is there an easy way to only display the top 5, and just cut the others off?

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/yxafa/

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="type 'r'" list="searchresults" autocomplete="off">
<datalist id="searchresults">
    <option>Ray0</option>
    <option>Ray1</option>
    <option>Ray2</option>
    <option>Ray3</option>
    <option>Ray01</option>
    <option>Ray11</option>
    <option>Ray21</option>
    <option>Ray31</option>
    <option>Ray02</option>
    <option>Ray12</option>
    <option>Ray22</option>
    <option>Ray32</option>
    <option>Ray012</option>
    <option>Ray112</option>
    <option>Ray212</option>
    <option>Ray312</option>
    <option>Ray03</option>
    <option>Ray13</option>
    <option>Ray23</option>
    <option>Ray33</option>
    <option>Ray013</option>
    <option>Ray113</option>
    <option>Ray213</option>
    <option>Ray313</option>
    <option>Ray023</option>
    <option>Ray123</option>
    <option>Ray223</option>
    <option>Ray323</option>
    <option>Ray0123</option>
    <option>Ray1123</option>
    <option>Ray2123</option>
    <option>Ray3123</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: Come on! Interesting question, +1! Why there are no answers!?

Comment: Well, i don't think this i possible atm. You can only reduce the set of displayed items by adding other requirement like `maxlength="4"` or  `pattern="Ray[0123]\d"`

Comment: Also note that, at the time of writing (May 2014) the `template` tag is only supported in Chrome, Opera Desktop, and Mozilla FF. [See here](http://caniuse.com/#search=template). Same for [`datalist`](http://caniuse.com/#search=datalist), + partial support for IE 10+

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With some modern javascript and html you could do something like this.

Here's the document:

```
<template id="resultstemplate">
    <option>Ray0</option>
    <option>Ray1</option>
    <option>Ray2</option>
    <option>Ray3</option>
    <option>Ray01</option>
    <option>Ray11</option>
    <option>Ray21</option>
    <option>Ray31</option>
    <option>Ray02</option>
    <option>Ray12</option>
    <option>Ray22</option>
    <option>Ray32</option>
    <option>Ray012</option>
    <option>Ray112</option>
    <option>Ray212</option>
    <option>Ray312</option>
    <option>Ray03</option>
    <option>Ray13</option>
    <option>Ray23</option>
    <option>Ray33</option>
    <option>Ray013</option>
    <option>Ray113</option>
    <option>Ray213</option>
    <option>Ray313</option>
    <option>Ray023</option>
    <option>Ray123</option>
    <option>Ray223</option>
    <option>Ray323</option>
    <option>Ray0123</option>
    <option>Ray1123</option>
    <option>Ray2123</option>
    <option>Ray3123</option>
</template>
<input type="text" name="search" id="search"  placeholder="type 'r'" list="searchresults" autocomplete="off" />
<datalist id="searchresults"></datalist>
```

And here's the js:

```
var search = document.querySelector('#search');
var results = document.querySelector('#searchresults');
var templateContent = document.querySelector('#resultstemplate').content;
search.addEventListener('keyup', function handler(event) {
    while (results.children.length) results.removeChild(results.firstChild);
    var inputVal = new RegExp(search.value.trim(), 'i');
    var clonedOptions = templateContent.cloneNode(true);
    var set = Array.prototype.reduce.call(clonedOptions.children, function searchFilter(frag, el) {
        if (inputVal.test(el.textContent) && frag.children.length < 5) frag.appendChild(el);
        return frag;
    }, document.createDocumentFragment());
    results.appendChild(set);
});
```

And here's a live example:
http://jsfiddle.net/gildean/yxafa/6/

Comment: Just wonderin', why use `document.querySelector` in this case instead of `getElementById` when the latter is much faster & more efficient? http://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector

Comment: It's just a nicer api to remember. And in this example we're only doing all of the selecting once, so it makes no difference.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer to the original question (where the developer **wants to limit** the items shown in the datalist)

However I arrived at this question because I was concerned about a different limitation (where the developers does **not want to limit** the items shown in the datalist; but the **browser has a limit** ([Chrome has a limit of 512](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57729328/is-there-a-shim-or-polyfill-that-addresses-chromes-512-limitation-on-datalists); only shows up to 512 options at a time)

[This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bvgmw9on/2/) demonstrates the problem; see screenshot below.

Of course, as the user begins typing in the input (which filters the options shown in the datalist), there may be fewer than 512 results, *so this browser-limitation would not be noticeable*. But if your user expects to see every single option in your datalist and the filtered results count >512, be careful of the Chrome limitation.

```
searchresults = document.getElementById('searchresults');

// Even though you add 1000 options to the datalist 
// chrome will only show up to 512 of those options at one time
for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  let option = document.createElement('option');
  option.innerText = 'Val ' + (i+1);
  searchresults.appendChild(option);
}
```

[image: on the left, code shows adding 1000 options to a datalist, on the right the UI shows only up to 512 of those options will be listed at once]

If you need to show > 512 options...

Consider a [`<select>` instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) (in many browser implementations, a user can focus on a select, start typing, and in doing so "filter" the selected option. But this is limited to searching the start of a word, and may not handle special characters.)

Consider a UI library with "autocomplete"/"combobox" control ([example in KendoUI's "Combobox"](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/combobox/index)) or creating your own ([example in AngularJS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9MN-pi2GMw4))

Answer (score 1):

No javascript example:

```
  <input list="site" name="f" minlength="2" style="height:5.1em">
  <datalist id="site" style="height:5.1em;overflow:hidden">
```

Took me a minute :)

This uses CSS style and HTML attributes.
PS: The minimum length should protect against empty submissions.
However, you'll need to select the object and then hit backspace to see :|

Comment: a minute of experimenting, and a minute for explanation. I'm sure you can do better explanation of the settings.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. The extra entries will be hidden, because they will exceed the height of "5.1em". I've edited the example to include "overflow:hidden".