# How to find datalist template options innerHTML value?

Tags: javascript, html, html-datalist, html-templates

I wanted to know how to limit the number of `datalist options` displayed on a `datalist` dropdown.

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15097563/limit-total-entries-displayed-by-datalist) which uses a `datalist` wrapping around a `template`, plus some javascript.

But, I want return the `innerHTML` corresponding to the selected `datalist option`. So, if I select `option value = "California"` I want to return `>"CA"<`.

```
document.getElementById("optionInnerHTML").innerHTML = [].find.call(document.getElementById('searchresults').getElementsByTagName('option'), ({ value }) => value === a).innerHTML;
```

I've tried adding `document.getElementById('resultstemplate')` to the code above however nothing  has worked. What do I need to change to make the function return the `option innerHTML` value?

**Before** adding the `datalist options` limit (notice that the displayed dropdown options aren't limited yet, but I successfully get the `option innerHTML` value:

```js
/* listen for ENTER click to submit datalist option input */  
function loadDoc() {
var n = document.getElementById("search");
n.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        document.getElementById("myButton").click();
}
});
    
/* find search value */  
var n = document.getElementById("search");
var a = n.value;
document.getElementById("searchValue").innerHTML = a;
    
/* find datalist option innerHTML */  
document.getElementById("optionInnerHTML").innerHTML = [].find.call(document.getElementById('searchresults').getElementsByTagName('option'), ({ value }) => value === a).innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<datalist id="searchresults">
<option value="Alabama">AL</option>
<option value="California">CA</option>
<option value="Florida">FL</option>
<option value="Michigan">MI</option>
<option value="New York">NY</option>
<option value="Wisconsin">WI</option>
</datalist>
    
<input type="text" name="search" id="search"  placeholder="type state name or code" list="searchresults" autocomplete="off" />

<button id="myButton" type="button"
onclick="loadDoc()">Submit
</button>

<p>search value: <span id="searchValue"></span></p>
<p>datalist option innerHTML: <span id="optionInnerHTML"></span></p>
```

**After** adding the `<template>` and `datalist options` limit (Notice how the displayed `options` are now limited during input, but on submit I no longer get the `option innerHTML` value):

```js
/* Limit length of datalist options dropdown */
var search = document.querySelector('#search');
var results = document.querySelector('#searchresults');
var templateContent = document.querySelector('#resultstemplate').content;
search.addEventListener('keyup', function handler(event) {
    while (results.children.length) results.removeChild(results.firstChild);
    var inputVal = new RegExp(search.value.trim(), 'i');
    var clonedOptions = templateContent.cloneNode(true);
    var set = Array.prototype.reduce.call(clonedOptions.children, function searchFilter(frag, el) {
        if ((inputVal.test(el.textContent) || inputVal.test(el.value)) && (search.value != el.value) && frag.children.length < 5) frag.appendChild(el);
        return frag;
    }, document.createDocumentFragment());
    results.appendChild(set);
});


/* listen for ENTER click to submit datalist option input */  
function loadDoc() {
var n = document.getElementById("search");
n.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        document.getElementById("myButton").click();
}
});
    
/* find search value */  
var n = document.getElementById("search");
var a = n.value;
document.getElementById("searchValue").innerHTML = a;
    
/* find datalist option innerHTML */  
document.getElementById("optionInnerHTML").innerHTML = [].find.call(document.getElementById('searchresults').getElementsByTagName('option'), ({ value }) => value === a);
}
```

```html
<datalist id="searchresults">
<template id="resultstemplate">
<option value="Alabama">AL</option>
<option value="California">CA</option>
<option value="Florida">FL</option>
<option value="Michigan">MI</option>
<option value="New York">NY</option>
<option value="Wisconsin">WI</option>
</template>
</datalist>
    
<input type="text" name="search" id="search"  placeholder="type state name or code" list="searchresults" autocomplete="off" />

<button id="myButton" type="button"
onclick="loadDoc()">Submit
</button>

<p>search value: <span id="searchValue"></span></p>
<p>datalist option innerHTML: <span id="optionInnerHTML"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have the template saved off, you can use it to search for the matching option:

```
const options = templateContent.querySelectorAll('option');
const matchingOption = [].find.call(options, ({ value }) => value === a);
document.getElementById("optionInnerHTML").innerHTML = matchingOption.innerHTML;
```

Full working example:

```js
/* Limit length of datalist options dropdown */
var search = document.querySelector('#search');
var results = document.querySelector('#searchresults');
var templateContent = document.querySelector('#resultstemplate').content;
search.addEventListener('keyup', function handler(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      return;
    }

    while (results.children.length) results.removeChild(results.firstChild);
    var inputVal = new RegExp(search.value.trim(), 'i');
    var clonedOptions = templateContent.cloneNode(true);
    var set = Array.prototype.reduce.call(clonedOptions.children, function searchFilter(frag, el) {
        if ((inputVal.test(el.textContent) || inputVal.test(el.value)) && (search.value != el.value) && frag.children.length < 5) frag.appendChild(el);
        return frag;
    }, document.createDocumentFragment());
    results.appendChild(set);
});


/* listen for ENTER click to submit datalist option input */  
function loadDoc() {
var n = document.getElementById("search");
n.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        document.getElementById("myButton").click();
}
});
    
/* find search value */  
var n = document.getElementById("search");
var a = n.value;
document.getElementById("searchValue").innerHTML = a;
    
/* find datalist option innerHTML */  
const matchingOption = [].find.call(templateContent.querySelectorAll('option'), ({ value }) => value === a);
document.getElementById("optionInnerHTML").innerHTML = matchingOption.innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<datalist id="searchresults">
<template id="resultstemplate">
<option value="Alabama">AL</option>
<option value="California">CA</option>
<option value="Florida">FL</option>
<option value="Michigan">MI</option>
<option value="New York">NY</option>
<option value="Wisconsin">WI</option>
</template>
</datalist>
    
<input type="text" name="search" id="search"  placeholder="type state name or code" list="searchresults" autocomplete="off" />

<button id="myButton" type="button"
onclick="loadDoc()">Submit
</button>

<p>search value: <span id="searchValue"></span></p>
<p>datalist option innerHTML: <span id="optionInnerHTML"></span></p>
```

Comment: This is a great answer. Thank you!