# Seach dropdown doesn't show the all options

Tags: javascript, html

I need to show about 650 values in a search dropdown but when i run the code below the dropdown shows just 513 values.

How can i show all 650 values in dropdown.

PS: I know the code is so long, I tried to get the values with api but my html ability is limited :(

```html
<h1>Dropdown with searchable text</h1>
<form>
  <label for="myValue">Choose the value</label>
  <input list="values" id="myValue" name="myValue" placeholder="type here..." />
  <datalist id="values">
<option value="A1">A1</option>
<option value="A2">A2</option>
<option value="A3">A3</option>
<option value="A4">A4</option>
<option value="A5">A5</option>
<option value="A6">A6</option>
<option value="A7">A7</option>
<option value="A8">A8</option>
<option value="A9">A9</option>
<option value="A10">A10</option>
<option value="A11">A11</option>
<option value="A12">A12</option>
<option value="A13">A13</option>
<option value="A14">A14</option>
<option value="A15">A15</option>
<option value="A16">A16</option>
<option value="A17">A17</option>
<option value="A18">A18</option>
<option value="A19">A19</option>
<option value="A20">A20</option>
<option value="A21">A21</option>
<option value="A22">A22</option>
<option value="A23">A23</option>
<option value="A24">A24</option>
<option value="A25">A25</option>
<option value="A26">A26</option>
<option value="A27">A27</option>
<option value="A28">A28</option>
<option value="A29">A29</option>
<option value="A30">A30</option>
<option value="A31">A31</option>
<option value="A32">A32</option>
<option value="A33">A33</option>
<option value="A34">A34</option>
<option value="A35">A35</option>
<option value="A36">A36</option>
<option value="A37">A37</option>
<option value="A38">A38</option>
<option value="A39">A39</option>
<option value="A40">A40</option>
<option value="A41">A41</option>
<option value="A42">A42</option>
<option value="A43">A43</option>
<option value="A44">A44</option>
<option value="A45">A45</option>
<option value="A46">A46</option>
<option value="A47">A47</option>
<option value="A48">A48</option>
<option value="A49">A49</option>
<option value="A50">A50</option>
<option value="A51">A51</option>
<option value="A52">A52</option>
<option value="A53">A53</option>
<option value="A54">A54</option>
<option value="A55">A55</option>
<option value="A56">A56</option>
<option value="A57">A57</option>
<option value="A58">A58</option>
<option value="A59">A59</option>
<option value="A60">A60</option>
<option value="A61">A61</option>
<option value="A62">A62</option>
<option value="A63">A63</option>
<option value="A64">A64</option>
<option value="A65">A65</option>
<option value="A66">A66</option>
<option value="A67">A67</option>
<option value="A68">A68</option>
<option value="A69">A69</option>
<option value="A70">A70</option>
<option value="A71">A71</option>
<option value="A72">A72</option>
<option value="A73">A73</option>
<option value="A74">A74</option>
<option value="A75">A75</option>
<option value="A76">A76</option>
<option value="A77">A77</option>
<option value="A78">A78</option>
<option value="A79">A79</option>
<option value="A80">A80</option>
<option value="A81">A81</option>
<option value="A82">A82</option>
<option value="A83">A83</option>
<option value="A84">A84</option>
<option value="A85">A85</option>
<option value="A86">A86</option>
<option value="A87">A87</option>
<option value="A88">A88</option>
<option value="A89">A89</option>
<option value="A90">A90</option>
<option value="A91">A91</option>
<option value="A92">A92</option>
<option value="A93">A93</option>
<option value="A94">A94</option>
<option value="A95">A95</option>
<option value="A96">A96</option>
<option value="A97">A97</option>
<option value="A98">A98</option>
<option value="A99">A99</option>
<option value="A100">A100</option>
<option value="A101">A101</option>
<option value="A102">A102</option>
<option value="A103">A103</option>
<option value="A104">A104</option>
<option value="A105">A105</option>
<option value="A106">A106</option>
<option value="A107">A107</option>
<option value="A108">A108</option>
<option value="A109">A109</option>
<option value="A110">A110</option>
<option value="A111">A111</option>
<option value="A112">A112</option>
<option value="A113">A113</option>
<option value="A114">A114</option>
<option value="A115">A115</option>
<option value="A116">A116</option>
<option value="A117">A117</option>
<option value="A118">A118</option>
<option value="A119">A119</option>
<option value="A120">A120</option>
<option value="A121">A121</option>
<option value="A122">A122</option>
<option value="A123">A123</option>
<option value="A124">A124</option>
<option value="A125">A125</option>
<option value="A126">A126</option>
<option value="A127">A127</option>
<option value="A128">A128</option>
<option value="A129">A129</option>
<option value="A130">A130</option>
<option value="A131">A131</option>
<option value="A132">A132</option>
<option value="A133">A133</option>
<option value="A134">A134</option>
<option value="A135">A135</option>
<option value="A136">A136</option>
<option value="A137">A137</option>
<option value="A138">A138</option>
<option value="A139">A139</option>
<option value="A140">A140</option>
<option value="A141">A141</option>
<option value="A142">A142</option>
<option value="A143">A143</option>
<option value="A144">A144</option>
<option value="A145">A145</option>
<option value="A146">A146</option>
<option value="A147">A147</option>
<option value="A148">A148</option>
<option value="A149">A149</option>
<option value="A150">A150</option>
<option value="A151">A151</option>
<option value="A152">A152</option>
<option value="A153">A153</option>
<option value="A154">A154</option>
<option value="A155">A155</option>
<option value="A156">A156</option>
<option value="A157">A157</option>
<option value="A158">A158</option>
<option value="A159">A159</option>
<option value="A160">A160</option>
<option value="A161">A161</option>
<option value="A162">A162</option>
<option value="A163">A163</option>
<option value="A164">A164</option>
<option value="A165">A165</option>
<option value="A166">A166</option>
<option value="A167">A167</option>
<option value="A168">A168</option>
<option value="A169">A169</option>
<option value="A170">A170</option>
<option value="A171">A171</option>
<option value="A172">A172</option>
<option value="A173">A173</option>
<option value="A174">A174</option>
<option value="A175">A175</option>
<option value="A176">A176</option>
<option value="A177">A177</option>
<option value="A178">A178</option>
<option value="A179">A179</option>
<option value="A180">A180</option>
<option value="A181">A181</option>
<option value="A182">A182</option>
<option value="A183">A183</option>
<option value="A184">A184</option>
<option value="A185">A185</option>
<option value="A186">A186</option>
<option value="A187">A187</option>
<option value="A188">A188</option>
<option value="A189">A189</option>
<option value="A190">A190</option>
<option value="A191">A191</option>
<option value="A192">A192</option>
<option value="A193">A193</option>
<option value="A194">A194</option>
<option value="A195">A195</option>
<option value="A196">A196</option>
<option value="A197">A197</option>
<option value="A198">A198</option>
<option value="A199">A199</option>
<option value="A200">A200</option>
<option value="A201">A201</option>
<option value="A202">A202</option>
<option value="A203">A203</option>
<option value="A204">A204</option>
<option value="A205">A205</option>
<option value="A206">A206</option>
<option value="A207">A207</option>
<option value="A208">A208</option>
<option value="A209">A209</option>
<option value="A210">A210</option>
<option value="A211">A211</option>
<option value="A212">A212</option>
<option value="A213">A213</option>
<option value="A214">A214</option>
<option value="A215">A215</option>
<option value="A216">A216</option>
<option value="A217">A217</option>
<option value="A218">A218</option>
<option value="A219">A219</option>
<option value="A220">A220</option>
<option value="A221">A221</option>
<option value="A222">A222</option>
<option value="A223">A223</option>
<option value="A224">A224</option>
<option value="A225">A225</option>
<option value="A226">A226</option>
<option value="A227">A227</option>
<option value="A228">A228</option>
<option value="A229">A229</option>
<option value="A230">A230</option>
<option value="A231">A231</option>
<option value="A232">A232</option>
<option value="A233">A233</option>
<option value="A234">A234</option>
<option value="A235">A235</option>
<option value="A236">A236</option>
<option value="A237">A237</option>
<option value="A238">A238</option>
<option value="A239">A239</option>
<option value="A240">A240</option>
<option value="A241">A241</option>
<option value="A242">A242</option>
<option value="A243">A243</option>
<option value="A244">A244</option>
<option value="A245">A245</option>
<option value="A246">A246</option>
<option value="A247">A247</option>
<option value="A248">A248</option>
<option value="A249">A249</option>
<option value="A250">A250</option>
<option value="A251">A251</option>
<option value="A252">A252</option>
<option value="A253">A253</option>
<option value="A254">A254</option>
<option value="A255">A255</option>
<option value="A256">A256</option>
<option value="A257">A257</option>
<option value="A258">A258</option>
<option value="A259">A259</option>
<option value="A260">A260</option>
<option value="A261">A261</option>
<option value="A262">A262</option>
<option value="A263">A263</option>
<option value="A264">A264</option>
<option value="A265">A265</option>
<option value="A266">A266</option>
<option value="A267">A267</option>
<option value="A268">A268</option>
<option value="A269">A269</option>
<option value="A270">A270</option>
<option value="A271">A271</option>
<option value="A272">A272</option>
<option value="A273">A273</option>
<option value="A274">A274</option>
<option value="A275">A275</option>
<option value="A276">A276</option>
<option value="A277">A277</option>
<option value="A278">A278</option>
<option value="A279">A279</option>
<option value="A280">A280</option>
<option value="A281">A281</option>
<option value="A282">A282</option>
<option value="A283">A283</option>
<option value="A284">A284</option>
<option value="A285">A285</option>
<option value="A286">A286</option>
<option value="A287">A287</option>
<option value="A288">A288</option>
<option value="A289">A289</option>
<option value="A290">A290</option>
<option value="A291">A291</option>
<option value="A292">A292</option>
<option value="A293">A293</option>
<option value="A294">A294</option>
<option value="A295">A295</option>
<option value="A296">A296</option>
<option value="A297">A297</option>
<option value="A298">A298</option>
<option value="A299">A299</option>
<option value="A300">A300</option>
<option value="A301">A301</option>
<option value="A302">A302</option>
<option value="A303">A303</option>
<option value="A304">A304</option>
<option value="A305">A305</option>
<option value="A306">A306</option>
<option value="A307">A307</option>
<option value="A308">A308</option>
<option value="A309">A309</option>
<option value="A310">A310</option>
<option value="A311">A311</option>
<option value="A312">A312</option>
<option value="A313">A313</option>
<option value="A314">A314</option>
<option value="A315">A315</option>
<option value="A316">A316</option>
<option value="A317">A317</option>
<option value="A318">A318</option>
<option value="A319">A319</option>
<option value="A320">A320</option>
<option value="A321">A321</option>
<option value="A322">A322</option>
<option value="A323">A323</option>
<option value="A324">A324</option>
<option value="A325">A325</option>
<option value="A326">A326</option>
<option value="A327">A327</option>
<option value="A328">A328</option>
<option value="A329">A329</option>
<option value="A330">A330</option>
<option value="A331">A331</option>
<option value="A332">A332</option>
<option value="A333">A333</option>
<option value="A334">A334</option>
<option value="A335">A335</option>
<option value="A336">A336</option>
<option value="A337">A337</option>
<option value="A338">A338</option>
<option value="A339">A339</option>
<option value="A340">A340</option>
<option value="A341">A341</option>
<option value="A342">A342</option>
<option value="A343">A343</option>
<option value="A344">A344</option>
<option value="A345">A345</option>
<option value="A346">A346</option>
<option value="A347">A347</option>
<option value="A348">A348</option>
<option value="A349">A349</option>
<option value="A350">A350</option>
<option value="A351">A351</option>
<option value="A352">A352</option>
<option value="A353">A353</option>
<option value="A354">A354</option>
<option value="A355">A355</option>
<option value="A356">A356</option>
<option value="A357">A357</option>
<option value="A358">A358</option>
<option value="A359">A359</option>
<option value="A360">A360</option>
<option value="A361">A361</option>
<option value="A362">A362</option>
<option value="A363">A363</option>
<option value="A364">A364</option>
<option value="A365">A365</option>
<option value="A366">A366</option>
<option value="A367">A367</option>
<option value="A368">A368</option>
<option value="A369">A369</option>
<option value="A370">A370</option>
<option value="A371">A371</option>
<option value="A372">A372</option>
<option value="A373">A373</option>
<option value="A374">A374</option>
<option value="A375">A375</option>
<option value="A376">A376</option>
<option value="A377">A377</option>
<option value="A378">A378</option>
<option value="A379">A379</option>
<option value="A380">A380</option>
<option value="A381">A381</option>
<option value="A382">A382</option>
<option value="A383">A383</option>
<option value="A384">A384</option>
<option value="A385">A385</option>
<option value="A386">A386</option>
<option value="A387">A387</option>
<option value="A388">A388</option>
<option value="A389">A389</option>
<option value="A390">A390</option>
<option value="A391">A391</option>
<option value="A392">A392</option>
<option value="A393">A393</option>
<option value="A394">A394</option>
<option value="A395">A395</option>
<option value="A396">A396</option>
<option value="A397">A397</option>
<option value="A398">A398</option>
<option value="A399">A399</option>
<option value="A400">A400</option>
<option value="A401">A401</option>
<option value="A402">A402</option>
<option value="A403">A403</option>
<option value="A404">A404</option>
<option value="A405">A405</option>
<option value="A406">A406</option>
<option value="A407">A407</option>
<option value="A408">A408</option>
<option value="A409">A409</option>
<option value="A410">A410</option>
<option value="A411">A411</option>
<option value="A412">A412</option>
<option value="A413">A413</option>
<option value="A414">A414</option>
<option value="A415">A415</option>
<option value="A416">A416</option>
<option value="A417">A417</option>
<option value="A418">A418</option>
<option value="A419">A419</option>
<option value="A420">A420</option>
<option value="A421">A421</option>
<option value="A422">A422</option>
<option value="A423">A423</option>
<option value="A424">A424</option>
<option value="A425">A425</option>
<option value="A426">A426</option>
<option value="A427">A427</option>
<option value="A428">A428</option>
<option value="A429">A429</option>
<option value="A430">A430</option>
<option value="A431">A431</option>
<option value="A432">A432</option>
<option value="A433">A433</option>
<option value="A434">A434</option>
<option value="A435">A435</option>
<option value="A436">A436</option>
<option value="A437">A437</option>
<option value="A438">A438</option>
<option value="A439">A439</option>
<option value="A440">A440</option>
<option value="A441">A441</option>
<option value="A442">A442</option>
<option value="A443">A443</option>
<option value="A444">A444</option>
<option value="A445">A445</option>
<option value="A446">A446</option>
<option value="A447">A447</option>
<option value="A448">A448</option>
<option value="A449">A449</option>
<option value="A450">A450</option>
<option value="A451">A451</option>
<option value="A452">A452</option>
<option value="A453">A453</option>
<option value="A454">A454</option>
<option value="A455">A455</option>
<option value="A456">A456</option>
<option value="A457">A457</option>
<option value="A458">A458</option>
<option value="A459">A459</option>
<option value="A460">A460</option>
<option value="A461">A461</option>
<option value="A462">A462</option>
<option value="A463">A463</option>
<option value="A464">A464</option>
<option value="A465">A465</option>
<option value="A466">A466</option>
<option value="A467">A467</option>
<option value="A468">A468</option>
<option value="A469">A469</option>
<option value="A470">A470</option>
<option value="A471">A471</option>
<option value="A472">A472</option>
<option value="A473">A473</option>
<option value="A474">A474</option>
<option value="A475">A475</option>
<option value="A476">A476</option>
<option value="A477">A477</option>
<option value="A478">A478</option>
<option value="A479">A479</option>
<option value="A480">A480</option>
<option value="A481">A481</option>
<option value="A482">A482</option>
<option value="A483">A483</option>
<option value="A484">A484</option>
<option value="A485">A485</option>
<option value="A486">A486</option>
<option value="A487">A487</option>
<option value="A488">A488</option>
<option value="A489">A489</option>
<option value="A490">A490</option>
<option value="A491">A491</option>
<option value="A492">A492</option>
<option value="A493">A493</option>
<option value="A494">A494</option>
<option value="A495">A495</option>
<option value="A496">A496</option>
<option value="A497">A497</option>
<option value="A498">A498</option>
<option value="A499">A499</option>
<option value="A500">A500</option>
<option value="A501">A501</option>
<option value="A502">A502</option>
<option value="A503">A503</option>
<option value="A504">A504</option>
<option value="A505">A505</option>
<option value="A506">A506</option>
<option value="A507">A507</option>
<option value="A508">A508</option>
<option value="A509">A509</option>
<option value="A510">A510</option>
<option value="A511">A511</option>
<option value="A512">A512</option>
<option value="A513">A513</option>
<option value="A514">A514</option>
<option value="A515">A515</option>
<option value="A516">A516</option>
<option value="A517">A517</option>
<option value="A518">A518</option>
<option value="A519">A519</option>
<option value="A520">A520</option>
<option value="A521">A521</option>
<option value="A522">A522</option>
<option value="A523">A523</option>
<option value="A524">A524</option>
<option value="A525">A525</option>
<option value="A526">A526</option>
<option value="A527">A527</option>
<option value="A528">A528</option>
<option value="A529">A529</option>
<option value="A530">A530</option>
<option value="A531">A531</option>
<option value="A532">A532</option>
<option value="A533">A533</option>
<option value="A534">A534</option>
<option value="A535">A535</option>
<option value="A536">A536</option>
<option value="A537">A537</option>
<option value="A538">A538</option>
<option value="A539">A539</option>
<option value="A540">A540</option>
<option value="A541">A541</option>
<option value="A542">A542</option>
<option value="A543">A543</option>
<option value="A544">A544</option>
<option value="A545">A545</option>
<option value="A546">A546</option>
<option value="A547">A547</option>
<option value="A548">A548</option>
<option value="A549">A549</option>
<option value="A550">A550</option>
<option value="A551">A551</option>
<option value="A552">A552</option>
<option value="A553">A553</option>
<option value="A554">A554</option>
<option value="A555">A555</option>
<option value="A556">A556</option>
<option value="A557">A557</option>
<option value="A558">A558</option>
<option value="A559">A559</option>
<option value="A560">A560</option>
<option value="A561">A561</option>
<option value="A562">A562</option>
<option value="A563">A563</option>
<option value="A564">A564</option>
<option value="A565">A565</option>
<option value="A566">A566</option>
<option value="A567">A567</option>
<option value="A568">A568</option>
<option value="A569">A569</option>
<option value="A570">A570</option>
<option value="A571">A571</option>
<option value="A572">A572</option>
<option value="A573">A573</option>
<option value="A574">A574</option>
<option value="A575">A575</option>
<option value="A576">A576</option>
<option value="A577">A577</option>
<option value="A578">A578</option>
<option value="A579">A579</option>
<option value="A580">A580</option>
<option value="A581">A581</option>
<option value="A582">A582</option>
<option value="A583">A583</option>
<option value="A584">A584</option>
<option value="A585">A585</option>
<option value="A586">A586</option>
<option value="A587">A587</option>
<option value="A588">A588</option>
<option value="A589">A589</option>
<option value="A590">A590</option>
<option value="A591">A591</option>
<option value="A592">A592</option>
<option value="A593">A593</option>
<option value="A594">A594</option>
<option value="A595">A595</option>
<option value="A596">A596</option>
<option value="A597">A597</option>
<option value="A598">A598</option>
<option value="A599">A599</option>
<option value="A600">A600</option>
<option value="A601">A601</option>
<option value="A602">A602</option>
<option value="A603">A603</option>
<option value="A604">A604</option>
<option value="A605">A605</option>
<option value="A606">A606</option>
<option value="A607">A607</option>
<option value="A608">A608</option>
<option value="A609">A609</option>
<option value="A610">A610</option>
<option value="A611">A611</option>
<option value="A612">A612</option>
<option value="A613">A613</option>
<option value="A614">A614</option>
<option value="A615">A615</option>
<option value="A616">A616</option>
<option value="A617">A617</option>
<option value="A618">A618</option>
<option value="A619">A619</option>
<option value="A620">A620</option>
<option value="A621">A621</option>
<option value="A622">A622</option>
<option value="A623">A623</option>
<option value="A624">A624</option>
<option value="A625">A625</option>
<option value="A626">A626</option>
<option value="A627">A627</option>
<option value="A628">A628</option>
<option value="A629">A629</option>
<option value="A630">A630</option>
<option value="A631">A631</option>
<option value="A632">A632</option>
<option value="A633">A633</option>
<option value="A634">A634</option>
<option value="A635">A635</option>
<option value="A636">A636</option>
<option value="A637">A637</option>
<option value="A638">A638</option>
<option value="A639">A639</option>
<option value="A640">A640</option>
<option value="A641">A641</option>
<option value="A642">A642</option>
<option value="A643">A643</option>
<option value="A644">A644</option>
<option value="A645">A645</option>
<option value="A646">A646</option>
<option value="A647">A647</option>
<option value="A648">A648</option>
<option value="A649">A649</option>
<option value="A650">A650</option>

</datalist>
</form>
```

Comment: Also see [Datalist not loading full options (only 512 items)](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/6519570/datalist-not-loading-full-options-only-512-items?hl=en#:~:text=For%20all%20datalist%20it%20display%20max%20512%20items%20in%20the%20dropdown.) and [Is there a shim or polyfill that addresses Chrome's 512 limitation on datalists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57729328/is-there-a-shim-or-polyfill-that-addresses-chromes-512-limitation-on-datalists).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

513 is one value away from 512 which is a bit based integer.
My guess is that 512/513 is the maximum able to display/ render. Might be browser dependend as well.

Check this sa post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74755547/16529984
512/513 is indeed a maxium value

Safari/Mac:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help, I checked the dropdown on my iPhone i saw the 650 values, the problem is related with Chrome